# Stop return information returning when using Set-AzStorageBlobContent

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am using Powershell to upload PDF files into a blob storage account using:

```
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File <local path> `
  -Container "<container name>" `
  -Blob <blob name> `
  -Context <storage account with key>`
  -StandardBlobTier Cool `
  -Force
```

This works fine, I have no problems with the code, files upload without issue. However, the return I get from doing this is an enormous amount of text, it looks like:
[image]

This is fine if I am doing a few files, but I am doing hundreds of thousands.  This ends up using up way too much memory when I run it, as a result of the amount of information returned.  How do I stop the massive amount of return info from writing to the blob?

I have tried:

```
[void] (Set-AzStorageBlobContent ...
```

And

```
$ret = Set-AzStorageBlobContent ...
```

Both still return the huge return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Out-Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-7.2):

> The Out-Null cmdlet sends its output to NULL, in effect, removing it from the pipeline and preventing the output to be displayed at the screen.

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-Null
```

Comment: Note that in PoweShell Core this is perfectly fine but is very inefficient in Windows PowerShell. `$null =` or `> $null` are better approaches